# Can't plot dots over tile on bokeh

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, bokeh

I am following https://towardsdatascience.com/exploring-and-visualizing-chicago-transit-data-using-pandas-and-bokeh-part-ii-intro-to-bokeh-5dca6c5ced10 example to plot some dots on a tile using longitude and latitude. Here is my code.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.tile_providers import CARTODBPOSITRON
p = figure(x_axis_type="mercator", y_axis_type="mercator")
p.add_tile(CARTODBPOSITRON)
p.circle(x = us['Evt_Latitude__c'],
         y = us['Evt_Longitude__c'])
output_notebook()
show(p)
```

Despite following the code step by step , my dots are not plotted on the US tile, but on a gray tile with no state name, demarcation, etc. etc. See attached, yet you can see the US shape and realize the geolocation actually worked [image]

What did I get wrong?

Comment: Offhand, seems like the tiles are not loading. Are you on closed/airgapped network? Are there any errors in your browsers JS console or network activity pane?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use those lines instead :

```
from bokeh.tile_providers import get_provider, Vendors 

tile_provider = get_provider(Vendors.CARTODBPOSITRON)

p.add_tile(tile_provider)
```

if this isn't working see if your Web Mercator format fits.

this is a converter from decimal to mercator

```
def wgs84_to_web_mercator(df, lon="x", lat="y"):
"""Converts decimal longitude/latitude to Web Mercator format"""
    k = 6378137
    df["x"] = df[lon] * (k * np.pi/180.0)
    df["y"] = np.log(np.tan((90 + df[lat]) * np.pi/360.0)) * k
    return df
```

hope it'll help.

Comment: thanks, indeed the mistake was that the coordinates were not changed to mercator..